# Most fields of PerformanceResourceTiming are zero, even though setting Timing-Allow-Origin to "*"

Tags: javascript, performance, electron

I have an Electron app that's loaded from "file://" origin, I need to measure timing of network activity initiated by my app. So, I'm doing a cross-origin job. [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/PerformanceResourceTiming#cross-origin_timing_information) says:

> Many of the resource timing properties are restricted to return 0 or an empty string when the resource is a cross-origin request. To expose cross-origin timing information, the `Timing-Allow-Origin` HTTP response header needs to be set.

So, in my main side of my Electron app I manually add this header:

```
window.webContents.session.webRequest.onHeadersReceived((details, callback) => {
    callback({
        responseHeaders: {
            ...details.responseHeaders,
            'Timing-Allow-Origin': '*'
        }
    });
});
```

But still it doesn't work, most fields are `0`. I need to measure `responseStart - requestStart`, but `responseStart` is `0`.